# Open google nearby Settings in android through Code

Tags: android, google-nearby, android-settings

how can I open google nearby Settings in android through code?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to open nearby Settings :

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(viewIntent)
```

Comment: your answer is redirecting me on location settings page, I want google nearby settings

Comment: @AshishChoudhary google nearby settings interacts with services like location actoins, play games togrther. So please tell me exact what type of nearby setting you want.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary For particular Nearby google service there is no intent. You have to intent to setting page first . Read explanation : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/issues/65